# $x^5 = 9^x$ Solution by Derivatives (Where Did I Go Wrong)?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Where is my solution to the following problem wrong?

Problem:
$x^5 = 9^x$   Solve for x.
$5x^4 = 9^x * \ln(9)$    d/dx both sides.
$5x^4 = x^5 * \ln(9)$    As stated in the problem 9^x is equal to x^5 so substitute that in here.
$5 = x * \ln(9)$   Divide x^5 by x^4 and get x.
$5 / \ln(9) = x$   Isolate variables.

But this is wrong! Where did I go wrong?  Was it in my derivation?  d/dx 9^x is 9^x * ln(9) so my derivative tables tell me.
Was it in substituting x^5 for 9^x?  That seems allowed as long as the equation has a solution.  And it does.  It's just not x = 5/ln(9).

Comment: Knowing that $f(x_0)=g(x_0)$ for a particular value, $x_0$, of $x$ does not tell you that $f'(x_0)=g'(x_0)$, and conversely.  In any case, the original problem has no real solutions.

Comment: $x=1\implies 1=0$ right?

Comment: Draw the curves $y=x$ & then $y=x^2$ : You will see that there are 2 Points in Common. Derivatives (& tangents) will not match at those 2 Points : There is no "logical reason" why Derivatives of 2 intersecting curves might or might not match !

Comment: I guess it's tempting to say "if two things are equal, then doing the same thing to them will be equal".  But you have to be careful as to what exactly the *things* are and what you are doing to them.  $f(x) = x^5$ and $g(x)=9^x$ are not the things that are being equal ($f(x)\ne g(x)$).  What is being equal is a single value $f(x_0)=g(x_0)$.  Taking the derivative not doing something to the single values $f(x_0),g(x_0)$.  Taking the derivative is doing something to the *functions* which are *not* equal

Comment: if you're willing to look into *non-real complex* solutions, non-real solustions do exist.
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Power%5Bx%2C5%5D%3DPower%5B9%2Cx%5D
Note 1: $W_n$ is a variation of the Lambert functions, which you can google.
Note 2: Logs and exponents of non-real numbers will take nontrivial time to understand.

Answer (score 5):

Your mistake is confusion between:

- $\forall x: f(x) = g(x)$
  $f$ and $g$ are the same function.  So it's correct to assume $f'(x) = g'(x)$, wherever the derivative exists.
- $\exists x: f(x) = g(x)$
  $f$ and $g$ are two *different* functions that just happen to intersect at one point $(x, f(x) = g(x))$.  It's possible that the graphs of $f$ and $g$ go through the intersection at different slopes/angles, which means that $f'(x) \ne g'(x)$.

The equation you're given is the example of the latter, with $f(x) = x^5$ and $g(x) = 9^x$.  Whose derivatives are $f'(x) = 5x^4$ and $g'(x) = 9^x \ln 9$.  And while $f'(x) = g'(x)$ for *some* $x$ (specifically, at $x \approx -0.5891010480475299$, which does *not* satisfy $f(x) = g(x)$), this is not the case for *all* $x$.  For example, $f'(0) = 0 \ne g'(0) = \ln 9$.

Comment: Thanks!  That is precisely my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

First note that if $x<0$, then $x^5<0<9^x$ so there are no solutions. $x=0$ is clearly not a solution; so if a real solution exists, it is positive.  Throughout this post $\log x$ will mean the natural log of x, not $\log_{10}x$.

If $x^5=9^x$, then we can take the (natural) logarithm of both sides to get $5\log x=x \log 9$, which rearranges to
$$f(x)=\frac{\log 9}{5}$$
where $f(x)=\frac{\log x}{x}$.

It's easy to see that $f(x)$ is negative for $0<x<1$ and positive for $x>1$; as $x\to\infty$, $f(x)\to 0$.

The derivative of $f(x)$ is
$$f'(x)=\frac{\log x-1}{x^2}$$

which has a unique root corresponding to a maximum at $x=e$ (we know it's a maximum from what we found above; alternatively note that the derivative is positive for $0<x<e$ and negative for $x>e$).

But $f(e)=e^{-1}<\frac{\log 9}{5}$ and so there are no real solutions.

Comment: Clarification: You're using $\log u = \log_e u=\ln u$, right?  Not $\log u = \log_{10} u$.  I think most U.S. textbooks use the second interpretation, a certain percentage do use the first interpretation.

Comment: Yes, I'm using natural logarithms. I'll edit to clarify.